# London system move order

Tags: opening, london-system

The standard London System consists of the setup moves: d4, Bf4, e3, Nf3, Nbd2, c3, Bd3. I'm wondering about the nuances of what the most accurate move order is to play it in. Here are some of my thoughts:

Some people like reaching the London via 1.d4 Nf6 2.Nf3, but I like playing 2.Bf4; that way, you can go for the more aggressive setup with 3.Nc3 against King's Indian players, potentially tricking them into a Pirc.

Against people who play symmetrically, ie. 1.d4 d5 2.Bf4 Bf5, I like playing an early c4 instead of c3 to break symmetry.

If White plays Nf3 early, Black can play a combination of Nc6-Nh5 to harass / potentially trap the London bishop (since the queen has lost vision of h5) and force it to move off its natural diagonal, which can be annoying.

```
    [FEN ""]

    1.d4 d5 2.Bf4 Nf6 3.e3 c5 4.Nf3 Nc6 5.Nbd2 Nh5
```

If Black follows the main line setup with d5/Nf6/c5/Nc6/Qb6, it seems more accurate to play Nbd2 before c3, in case Black decides to enter the sharp gambit lines with dxc5 / Qxb2.

```
    [FEN ""]

    1. d4 d5 2.Bf4 Nf6 3.e3 c5 4.Nf3 Nc6 5. Nbd2 Qb6 6.dxc5 Qxb2 7.Rb1
```

In the main line, most masters seem to prefer the move order with d4-Bf4-e3-c3-Nd2; I'm not sure why this is.

```
    [FEN ""]

    1. d4 d5 2. Bf4 Nf6 3. e3 c5 4. c3 Nc6 5. Nd2
```

Why do masters prefer the above move order, and what other nuances am I missing from my points here?

Comment: I'll just note that as a Pirc (but not KI) player I very much enjoy that transposition ... Make sure you understand it!

Comment: Incidentally, I also play this move order although I played it at least a decade before the London System even got a name :-) (The most annoying thing with Bf4 is a Q attack on b2.)

Answer (score 3):

The early Nd2 gives some breathing room for your a1 rook

```
       [FEN ""]
       1. d4 d5 2. Bf4 Nf6 3. e3 c5 4. c3 Nc6 5. Nf3 Qb6 6. Qb3 c4 7. Qc2 Bf5 8. Qc1 (5. Nd2 Qb6 6. Qb3 c4 7. Qc2 g6 8. e4)
```

Notice how black cannot easily harass your queen and get a lead in development with Bf5 in the early Nd2 case

Comment: Sure, but that's why I usually go Nf3-Nd2 if Black has the potential of going for the early Qb6 line.

Answer (score 0):

Delaying the development of the Ng1 sometimes allow f2-f4, hoping to reach a perfect construction that Black usually avoids why the "normal" move order:

```
       [FEN ""]
       1. d4 d5 2. Bf4 Nf6 3. e3 c5 4. c3 Nc6 5. Bd3 (5. Nf3 e6 (5...Qb6) 6. Bd3 Bd6 7. Bg3 O-O 8. Nbd2 cxd4 9. exd4 Dc7 {prevents Ne5}) (5. Nd2 Bf5!?) e6 6. Nd2 Bd6 7.Bg3 O-O 8. f4!? Qc7 9. Ngf3 {followed by Ne5}
```

This shape with a Ne5 supported by the pawns on d4 and f4 is often attributed to Pillsbury and is very appreciated by London System players.